# PHPChart won't accept variables within data array

Tags: php

I've searched everywhere for an answer to this, and I truly do hate asking what is probably a really simple question, but I am lost.

This is the code I'm using to display a pie cart ...

```
$s1 = array(
                    array('Carpets',235000), 
                    array('Vinyl',35069), 
                    array('LVT',36911), 
                    array('Laminate',5243.97)
 );

    $pc = new C_PhpChartX(array($s1),'chart1');

    $pc->set_grid(array('drawBorder'=>true,
            'drawGridlines'=>false,
            'background'=>'#ffffff',
            'shadow'=>false));
    $pc->set_axes_default(array());

    $pc->set_series_default(array(
            'renderer'=>'plugin::PieRenderer',
            'rendererOptions'=>array('showDataLabels'=>true)));
    $pc->set_legend(array('show'=>true,
            'rendererOptions'=> array('numberRows'=> 1),
            'location'=> 's'));
    $pc->draw(400,400);
```

The chart works fine like this for testing purposes, but when I try and replace the data inside the data array with variables, no chart appears.  I think it may be to do with the way the data in the array is being passed to the JavaScript, but I am not skilled enough to fix.

The data is in variables ... $cTotal, $vTotal, $lTotal & $laTotal

I have echoed these and can confirm they are just producing an integer.

I have tried ...

```
$s1 = array(
        array('Carpets',$cTotal), 
        array('Vinyl',$vTotal), 
        array('LVT',$lTotal), 
        array('Laminate',$laTotal)
 );
```

As well as using "" and "{}", but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I figured it out.  For some reason when I used ...

```
$cTotal= $dataLabel['carpet'];
```

It echoed 236987.  But didn't work.  However, had a last minute thought and physically forced it to be an integer with ..

```
$cTotal= (int)$dataLabel['carpet'];
```

... and it worked.  I thought PHP was clever enough to figure that out for itself!